# apps script google drive auto remove editors

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sharing the folder / file in my Google drive to 'A'.

But now I'm trying to stop sharing to 'A'.

I tried to stop sharing all folders / files using apps script, but apps script could not execute for more than 5 minutes.

apps script Is there a better solution?

Comment: After you get the FileIterator for the files via DriveApp.searchFiles(searchParams), you can use my solution described here to beat the 5 minute execution quota https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985025/optimizing-google-sheets-appendrow/45987178#45987178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you exceeding the 5 minutes because you are iterating over **a lot** of files?

By the way, probably it is better to use the advanced API to perform this operation quicker (this is what comes from my *personal experience*, it maybe not true, but avoiding FileIterators tends to speed things up). Also, if you are iterating using `DriveApp.getFiles()` instead by searching directly the right ones, you are iterating over all files that you have in your drive, and it takes quite a lot.

Using the advanced API you may only iterate over the files that user `A` can modify/read (and even if you reach the 5 minutes, if you run again the function, the files/folders that you have already modified will be not taken into account by the query).

The file list can be obtained via (hypothesis: user `A` has mail address `a.mail@gmail.com`):

```
var files = Drive.Files.list({
  q: '"a.mail@gmail.com" in readers or "a.mail@gmail.com" in writers'
});


files.items.forEach(file => {
  var file_app = DriveApp.getFileById(file.id);
  // Do here what you need to stop sharing. 
});
```

The listing gets both files and folders. You can check this by using the property `file.mimeType` (it is `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` for folders, tha actual mimetype for the files, like `application/pdf` for a PDF).

**DISCLAIMER**: you **have to** enable the advanced API in both AppScript and Google Console. It is easy, just read carefully [the instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

**Test**: I tested this solution against the file shared with one of my colleague. We have in shared folders with more than 10000 files, and I succeed to iterate on all the files without reaching the limit. The `DriveApp` callback reached the limit. But again, this is personal tests, take it with cautions.

Comment: Really thank you for your answer. i have 1 more question. Is the execution time of 5 minutes only "apps script" execution time?
Or is it "time to connect to google service"?